# Append to an array within a specific index

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been really stumped for a while on this.
I have a loop like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < Quotes.length; i++) {
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    dataSets.push([[ timestamp, Quotes[i].unitprice ]]);
}
```

`dataSets` should be an array of `timestamp` and price data (`Quotes[i].unitprice`). Timestamp and price data is also an array which should be appended to for each stock; every update cycle when this loop is called.

How can I append to an array contained within a specific dataSets index.

Currently dataSets is defined in global scope as `dataSets = [[]]`.

I just want to be able to update the inner array on each index (`dataSets[i]`).

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: Say I have the stock quotes FOO and BAR; I want to be able to append to their index within `dataSets`. So where `dataSets[0]` is FOO and `dataSets[1]` is BAR,  I want to be able to update the timestamp and unit price array from [[134484, 1.40]] to [[134484, 1.40],[134487, 1.45]]

Comment: All these arrays are confusing me. Could you add some short example data and the changes you wish to make on it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply; added some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are looking for something like this. First create all the empty arrays within `dataSets`:

```
var dataSets = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < Quotes.length; ++i) {
    dataSets[i] = new Array();
}
```

Then append the data with:

```
dataSets[i].push([timestamp, Quotes[i].unitprice]);
```

Comment: I think this might be what I need yes, thank you. I'll try it out.